# Retrieving values in the drop down list from MySQL where one data is related to multiple data (PHP & MySQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table where a single food id is related to multiple supplier ids. Hence, I need to produce a result where the drop down menu can list those supplier ids which are related to the food ids. 
For instance the food id 1 is related to the supplier ids 1, 4 and 3. I need to put all those supplier ids related to the food id 1 in a drop down list. The rest can appear as they are in sequential order like in the case of food id 2.

```
|FOOD ID |  SUPPLIER ID (DROP DOWN LIST) |  OPTIONS I want in the drop down
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1       |  1                          |v|  1, 4 and 3 
|2       |  5                          |v|  5
```

I have been trying this for over a week now, and I have failed to do it in every attempt. Please help me out here guys. I need the same output as the second image guys. The site wouldn't allow me to post images. So sorry about that guys.

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');
$selectfood= mysql_query("
SELECT foodstock.stock_id, foodstock.foodid, food.food_id, food.food_name, foodstock.quantity, assignfoodtosup.supplierid
    FROM foodstock
    JOIN food
    ON foodstock.foodid=food.food_id
    JOIN assignfoodtosup
    ON food.food_id=assignfoodtosup.foodid      
    WHERE foodstock.quantity<10
    ");
$selectsupplier= mysql_query("
SELECT foodstock.stock_id, foodstock.foodid, food.food_id, food.food_name, foodstock.quantity, assignfoodtosup.supplierid
    FROM foodstock
    JOIN food
    ON foodstock.foodid=food.food_id
    JOIN assignfoodtosup
    ON food.food_id=assignfoodtosup.foodid      
    WHERE foodstock.quantity<10
    ");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Make Order</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th id="tdsn">S.No.</th>
<th id="tdfoodid">Food ID</th>
<th id="tdfoodname">Food Name</th>
<th id="tdstockqty">Stock Qty.</th>
<th id="tdorderqty">Order Qty.</th>
<th id="tdsupplierid">Supplier ID</th>
<th id="tdsuppliername">Supplier Name</th>
<th id="tdmorder">Make Order</th>
</tr>
<?php
    $count=0;
    $suppliercount=0;
    $stock_array[]=array();
    $result_array[]=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($selectsupplier)){
        $suppliercount++;
    $result_array[$suppliercount]=$row['supplierid'];
}
while($rowstock = mysql_fetch_array($selectfood)){ 
    $stock_array[] = $rowstock;
    $count++;

?>      
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $stock_array[$count]['foodid']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $stock_array[$count]['food_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $stock_array[$count]['quantity']; ?></td>        
            <td><input type="text" id="orderqty" name="orderqty" style="width:50px"></td>
            <td>
                <select id="supplierid" name="supplierid">
                     <option value="<?php echo $result_array[$count]; ?>"><?php echo $result_array[$count]; ?> </option>
                 </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="makeorder" name="makeorder" value="$count"></td>
        </tr>
<?php
} 
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Guys I have four tables

```
1) suppliers: suppliersID, suppliername.......
2) food: foodid, foodname.......
3) assignfoodtosup:assignfoodtosupid, supplierid, foodid
4) foodstock:foodid, foodname, quantity
```

The thing is, i have to make a table where i have to show those food whose quantity is less than 10. And I also have to show those suppliers who sell those food. As this is where I have to implement the code I was asking for, this is it.

Comment: I have made the changes. Please see what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few changes to your code. I think the biggest problem was that you're not looping over your *suppliers* array, called `$result_array` when you write your `select` options. Here I wrapped a `foreach` loop around the `<options>` to write out each *supplier id* selection.

Also, I'm guessing that you had duplicate *foods* listed wherever there are more than one *supplier*. So I took out the `assignfoodtosup` `JOIN` in your *foods* query so your *foods* aren't duplicated for each *supplier*. And took out unnecessary fields and the unnecessary `food` table `JOIN` from the *suppliers* query. That query could be shortened even further because I'm guessing you don't really need to limit this query to *foodstock* quantities less than 10.

And I changed how you prepare and access your *suppliers* array. First, the `[]` weren't necessary. Second, it's less error prone to use the `foodid` to link the *foods* and their *suppliers*, rather than a counter.

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');
$selectfood= mysql_query("
SELECT foodstock.stock_id, foodstock.foodid, food.food_id, food.food_name, foodstock.quantity
    FROM foodstock
    JOIN food
    ON foodstock.foodid=food.food_id     
    WHERE foodstock.quantity<10
    ");
$selectsupplier= mysql_query("
SELECT foodstock.stock_id, foodstock.foodid, assignfoodtosup.supplierid
    FROM foodstock
    JOIN assignfoodtosup
    ON foodstock.foodid=assignfoodtosup.foodid      
    WHERE foodstock.quantity<10
    ");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Make Order</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th id="tdsn">S.No.</th>
<th id="tdfoodid">Food ID</th>
<th id="tdfoodname">Food Name</th>
<th id="tdstockqty">Stock Qty.</th>
<th id="tdorderqty">Order Qty.</th>
<th id="tdsupplierid">Supplier ID</th>
<th id="tdsuppliername">Supplier Name</th>
<th id="tdmorder">Make Order</th>
</tr>
<?php

$count=0;
$food_suppliers=array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($selectsupplier)){
    // using the supplierid for both the key and the value to ensure there are no duplicates
    $food_suppliers[$row['foodid']][$row['supplierid']]=$row['supplierid'];
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($selectfood)){ 

?>      
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['foodid']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['food_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>        
            <td><input type="text" id="orderqty" name="orderqty" style="width:50px"></td>
            <td>
                <select id="supplierid" name="supplierid">
                    <?php foreach ( $food_suppliers[$row['foodid']] as $supplierid ) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $supplierid; ?>"><?php echo $supplierid; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                 </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="makeorder" name="makeorder" value="$count"></td>
        </tr>
<?php
} 
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you sir. I finally got it. I have been working on it for quite a long time now and maybe I was not thinking logically due to the excessive thinking. Didn't see that part of the logic there. Didn't notice that I wasn't looping for the drop down too. Also, my skills on programming is not much as I am just a starter. Thank you. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the logic; I am sure you can get the syntax from web.

**Database Tables:**

1) Food (id, name)

2) Suppliers (id, food_id, name)

**PHP Query**

```
SELECT * FROM `Suppliers` WHERE `food_id` is 1 // 1 is just an example. You can declare and call a variable here. *Check for the syntax*
```

The result will be an array. You will require to loop this array into your dropdown code.

Note: the `food_id` that is stored in `Supplier` table; will be inserted into it while that data-entry is done for the `food` table. So you need to make sure that your form processing code has that provision done. It basically acts as a link between the two. A common parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you sir. No offense. I am well aware of the logic but I don't know where am I making a mistake while coding and can't get the result. I have uploaded the exact code. Please refer to it and support me if you can. Thank you again.

Comment: You should have posted the code in the first go itself.. Anyways you are welcome..

Answer (score 0):

@stdahal I would like to suggest you some other ways to get it done around, since your logic seems not perfect you scenario,

```
    <?php
require_once('connect.php');
$selectfood= mysql_query("select foodstock.id,foodstock.food_name,foodstock.quantity,foodstock.foodid from foodstock");    
$selectsuppliers = mysql_query("select assignfoodtosup.foodid,assignfoodtosup.supplierid from suppliers join assignfoodtosup on supplierid=suppliersID");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Make Order</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th id="tdsn">S.No.</th>
<th id="tdfoodid">Food ID</th>
<th id="tdfoodname">Food Name</th>
<th id="tdstockqty">Stock Qty.</th>
<th id="tdorderqty">Order Qty.</th>
<th id="tdsupplierid">Supplier ID</th>
<th id="tdsuppliername">Supplier Name</th>
<th id="tdmorder">Make Order</th>
</tr>
<?php
    $count=0;
    $suppliercount=0;
    $stock_array[]=array();
    $result_array[]=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($selectsuppliers)){
        $result_array[$row["foodid"]][] = $row["supplierid"]; 
    }
    while($rowstock = mysql_fetch_array($selectfood)){ 
    $count++;

?>      
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowstock['foodid']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowstock['food_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowstock['quantity']; ?></td>        
            <td><input type="text" id="orderqty" name="orderqty" style="width:50px"></td>
            <td>
                <select id="supplierid" name="supplierid">
                     <?php foreach ($result_array[$rowstock['foodid']] as $key => $value) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?> </option>
                    <?php }?>

                 </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="makeorder" name="makeorder" value="$count"></td>
        </tr>
<?php
} 
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it will help you better..

Comment: Thank you sir. But the code didn't work. Did you check it in my code itself?

Comment: @yugesh please have a look at my updated code, and hope this will solve your problem but as per your comments it seems that you are starting the coding before completing your homework.

Comment: I researched a lot about it on the web, but I couldn't work my way out of it. I was going towards the wrong direction from the beginning and trying to get back to the track was difficult as I put all the thinking to get back to the track. I should have started fresh again, rather than trying to get the code work again and again by making changes on it. P.S. I am just a beginner at programming and I lack a lot of skills. Moreover, I am learning from home so this makes it even difficult as I don't have anyone to consult to. Thank you sir. Thank you for your time.